# count of character from one position until it reaches a Space Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to take the count of character from one position until it reaches a Space Using VBA

Sub testing()
Dim YourText As String
YourText = "my name ismanu prasad"
Cells(1, 1).Value = Len(YourText)
End Sub

Above code will return 21 as output. But my scenario is bit different .I need the count of  substring “manu”  from the above string and output should be 4

Comment: Could you revise your question to include your code that you've tried?  Also, if you could say what the result you got and what problems you are having.   I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.  Possibly reword and break it down into steps.  I think I have an idea, but I'm not sure of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Display4thWord()
Dim Space As String
Dim YourText As String
Dim Begin4thWord As Integer
Dim End4thWord As Integer

YourText = "The first message box display a value"
Space = " "
'Find begin of 4th word.
Begin4thWord = InStr(InStr(InStr(1, YourText, Space, vbBinaryCompare) + 1, YourText,    Space, vbBinaryCompare) + 1, YourText, Space, vbBinaryCompare)
'Find end of 4th word/begin of 5th word
End4thWord = InStr(Begin4thWord + 1, YourText, Space, vbBinaryCompare)
MsgBox (Begin4thWord)

'Display 4th word
MsgBox (Mid(YourText, Begin4thWord, End4thWord - Begin4thWord))
End Sub
```

You need to embed InStr function and use with Mid function.
Is it satisfaction you? This solution have hard code number number of word which it will return.

Comment: Sub testing() Dim YourText As String YourText = "my name ismanu prasad" Cells(1, 1).Value = Len(YourText) End Sub Above code will return 21 as output. But my scenario is bit different .I need the count of substring “manu” from the above string and output should be 4

Comment: try this:

MsgBox (Left(YourText, End4thWord))
MsgBox (Right(Left(YourText, End4thWord), 4))

Answer (score -1):

Declare two variables recordnocount & recordnocount 
.position is the value we have

recordnocount = InStr(position + 20, text, " ")
recordnocount1 = recordnocount - (position + 20)

we can get the count .

Thankyou All